# Codepage 1252 file conversion

Tags: unicode, codepages

I am migrating a script from Windows to Linux.   The Windows script is doing the following conversion:

`chcp 1252`

type "source.csv" > "new.csv"

What is the equivalent command to perform the conversion on Linux?

Comment: [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, this worked for me

`iconv -f UTF-16 -t WINDOWS-1252 -o new.csv source.csv`